# how to get a variable out of a procedure in the right way in PASCAL?

Tags: pascal, procedure

I'm following an internet course on the basics of programming. After making a diagram I convert it to code, right now this is PASCAL language.
I'm having a problem with procedures and can't find an answer, nor in the course, nor with some google-ing.
I want to get a variavble back form a procedure. Right now iIhave a working piece of code but I think this is not the good way of working. Here's an extract of the code:

```
   program WELKEWAGEN;

   // declare your variables here
   var T, N, KM, vari, prijsDW, prijsBW, jrenGEBR, taksDW, taksBW, prijsB, verbrBW,         prijsD, verbrDW : real;

 procedure OPHALEN(para : string);
 begin
 repeat
 writeln('geef de ', para , ' op');
 readln(vari);
 until (vari > 0);
 end;

 begin   
 //this is the main program but there is more code ofcourse  
 OPHALEN('prijs benzinewagen');
 prijsBW := vari;
 //...
 end.
```

Now the internet course says I should program it like this:

```
begin
//...
prijsBW := OPHALEN('prijs benzinewagen');
//...
end.
```

But this is not working.
I get following errors:

```
WELKEWAGEN.pas(24,14) Error: Incompatible types: got "untyped" expected "Real"
WELKEWAGEN.pas(50) Fatal: There were 1 errors compiling module, stopping
```

`pas(24,14)` is this line: `prijsBW := OPHALEN('prijs benzinewagen');`

Comment: If you want to get a return value, you have to define a `Function`, not a `Procedure`. To return a value from the function, you assign to the function name. See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Pascal_Programming/Syntax_and_functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Procedures don't return values, so the syntax

```
prijsBW := OPHALEN('prijs benzinewagen');
```

is invalid.

If you want to return a value, you need to define a `function` instead:

```
function OPHALEN(para : string): Real;
var
  Res: Real;
begin
  Res := 0;
  repeat
    writeln('geef de ', para , ' op');
    readln(Res);
  until (Res > 0);
  OPHALEN := Res;
end;
```

Note that the (bad) global variables you're using mean you don't have to return anything at all, because a procedure can access and change that global variable directly (but you have no way of knowing when the procedure is finished):

```
procedure OPHALEN(para : string);
begin
  vari := 0;
  repeat
    writeln('geef de ', para , ' op');
    readln(vari);
  until (vari > 0);
end;
```

Modern Pascal dialects (such as Delphi and FreePascal) allow a cleaner syntax for the return value of functions by using an automatically declared function result variable of the proper type for you, named `Result` (because that's what it is - the result of the function):

```
function OPHALEN(para : string): Real;
begin
  Result := 0;
  repeat
    writeln('geef de ', para , ' op');
    readln(Result);
  until (Result > 0);
end;
```

If you need to return multiple values, you can use `var` parameters, which allow them to be changed inside the function.

```
procedure OPHALEN(para: string; var RetVal: Real);
begin
  RetVal := 0;
  repeat
    writeln('geef de ', para , ' op');
    readln(RetVal);
  until (RetVal > 0);
end;
```

Your original code (and the examples I've provided above) all fail to allow the user to cancel, BTW. There should be some way to exit the loop for the user; otherwise, your code just endlessly loops, writing `para` to the screen and then waiting for input. This has a tendency to annoy users.